# Strange behavior in model property "name" in form angular

Tags: angular

I hava model:

```
export class Sid {
  id: number;
  sid: string;
  name: string;
  describe: string;
}
```

and form:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 input-column">
    <input #name="ngModel" name="name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="sid.name" required minlength="4"/>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="name.touched || name.touched || name.submited">
    <div *ngIf="sid_name.errors?.required">This field is required</div>
    <div *ngIf="sid_name.errors?.minlength">Min length is set to 4</div>
</div>
```

and component:

```
export class SidFormComponent {

  sid: Sid;

  constructor(@Inject('SidService') private sidService: SidService, route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // TODO get id for edit than
    this.sid = new Sid();
    console.log(this.sid);
    console.log(route);
  }

  save(sidForm) {
    if (sidForm.valid) {
      this.sidService.save(this.sid).subscribe();
      // TODO return to list
    }
  }
```

It does not matter that it has created an empty `Sid` object that have in `name` property the object name.

[image]

In the model:

```
export class Sid {
  id: number;
  sid: string;
  name: string;
  describe: string;
}
```

after changing the sid.`name` property to sid.`sid_name`

```
export class Sid {
  id: number;
  sid: string;
  sid_name: string;
  describe: string;
}
```

everything works correctly.

But I do not want to change the REST that takes an object with the `name` property.

Somewhere I'm probably making a mistake but I do not know where.

Comment: What exactly is the problem, I'm having trouble understanding :) Where does `sid_name` even come from?

Comment: Thank you for the attention I have improved the description.

Comment: Still I don't understand what `sid_name` is for, or where it comes from? Why is there a difference between `name` and `sid_name`?